# how to run a console app threw debug or realise

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm learning how to make console apps in C# and when I tried using the exe in debug and release it opens then closes in like 0.1 millisecond anything I need to do to run the the exe

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` or `ReadKey()` this will stop the app from closing instantly and wait for user input

Answer (score 0):

Use Console.ReadLine();

Reads the next line of characters from the standard input stream.
One of the most common uses of the ReadLine method is to pause the program
execution before clearing the console and displaying new information to
it, or to prompt the user to press the Enter key before terminating the
application.

```
Console.ReadLine();
```